# symfony - get only time from a date time parameter after serialization

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony application, I have a variable for a datetime as shown in the entity level

```
/**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $time;
```

I am retrieving the time in my controller as shown

```
$data = array();

    foreach ($Messages as $Message)
    {

        array_push($data, $this->serialize($Message));
    }


    $response = new Response(json_encode($data), 200);
```

This is the serialize method

```
private function serialize(Message $Message) {
        return array(
            'message' => $Message->getMessage(),
            'regfk' => $Message->getRegistrationfk(),
            'carefk' => $Message->getCarefk(),
            'time' => $Message->getMessagedate(),
            'usertype' => $Message->getUsertype(),
        );
    }
```

In the response, I am getting time in the format,

```
"time":{"date":"2017-06-08 00:03:02","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}
```

Please how can I get only the time from the datetime variable

Comment: try with `array_push($data, $this->serialize($Message->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`

Comment: I am retrieving other values along side with the time in the array shown

Comment: Can you show them ?

Comment: have u shown the serialize method

Comment: oh ok, so you need to do the format here, give the code down there ;)

Comment: I upvoted the two correct answers. Thanks

Comment: Valid one of them to close the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
private function serialize(Message $Message) {
        return array(
            'message' => $Message->getMessage(),
            'regfk' => $Message->getRegistrationfk(),
            'carefk' => $Message->getCarefk(),
            'time' => $Message->getMessagedate()->format('H:i:s'),
            'usertype' => $Message->getUsertype(),
        );
    }
```

If you can't be sure `getMessagedate()` does always return a `\DateTime` Object you'll need to add a null check:

```
'time' => $Message->getMEssagedate() != null ? $Message->getMessagedate()->format('H:i:s') : '',
```

Comment: how can I get rid of the leading zeroes 00:03:02

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and check out which literals used in the format string you'd like. `G:i:s` changes the hour value without leading zeroes for example

Comment: I want to get the hours and the minutes only

Comment: Then `G:i` or `H:i` should do the trick one with leading zeroes within the hour value and the other one without

Answer (score 1):

You push a DateTime object that is normal that the response give you that so if you do that :

```
private function serialize(Message $Message) {
    return array(
        'message' => $Message->getMessage(),
        'regfk' => $Message->getRegistrationfk(),
        'carefk' => $Message->getCarefk(),
        'time' => $Message->getMessagedate()->format('G:i'),
        'usertype' => $Message->getUsertype(),
    );
}
```

that should work great

Comment: this returns the date as well instead of just the time

Comment: Changed that, also no more leading zero

Comment: if I want to retrieve just the date

Comment: same but 'Y-m-d' instead of G:i ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use time type here

```
/**
 * @Assert \Time()
 *
 */
private $time;
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Time.html

Comment: so what will be type value in the annotation

Comment: Try giving text type.